# $\exists G \in L'. G \iff \mathtt{True}(gn(\neg G))$ in the language $L'$ with Godel numbering $gn$ and $\mathtt{True}$ predicate?

Tags: logic

I am reading a paper [Definability of Truth in Probabilistic Logic](http://intelligence.org/files/DefinabilityTruthDraft.pdf)
. Given a language $L$ with the Godel numbering $gn:L \to \mathbb{N}$ the authors extend it with a predicate $\mathtt{True}$ to a language $L'$ where for all $L'$-theories the correctness property has to hold:

$\forall \phi \in L'. \mathtt{True}(gn(\phi)) \iff \phi$

Then they claim that one could define by a diagonalization a sentence $G$ satisfying the property:

$G \iff \mathtt{True}(gn(\neg G))$

and that is what I do not understand.

How could I show the existence of such a sentence in $L'$?

Comment: But he shows that it is impossible... About *diagonalization*, see [Gödel's Incompleteness Theorems](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/goedel-incompleteness/) : **2.4 Diagonalization, or “Self-reference”**

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Thanks, hence what I want to prove seems to follow from the diagonal lemma.

Comment: Yes; see [Tarski's undefinability theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarski%27s_undefinability_theorem) : "In particular, if A is a sentence of arithmetic then True(g(A)) holds in N if and only if A is true in N. Hence for all A, the Tarski T-sentence True(g(A)) ↔ A is true in N. But the *diagonal lemma* yields a counterexample to this equivalence, by giving a "Liar" sentence S such that S ↔ ¬True(g(S)) holds. Thus no L-formula True(n) can define T* [ the set of Gödel numbers of L-sentences true in N]."